# Error querying the api: This works in the web browser but not on mobile. (expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I'm new to react native and I'm not able to consume this api, when I start this app in the browser, it works fine, but when I go to the expo app it doesn't display the pokemon image, could someone help me?

```tsx
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button, Alert, TextInput, Image } from 'react-native';

interface PokeInterface {
  sprites : {
    back_default : string;
  }
}
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("")
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<PokeInterface | any>()
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>()
  const handleText = (text : string) => {
    setText(text)
  }

  const searchApi = (pokemonName : string) => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`, { method: 'GET'})
      .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => setResponse(response))

        
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    if(text){
      searchApi(text)
    }
    if(response){
      const {sprites} = response
      setImage(sprites.front_default)
    }

    return () => {
      if(image){
        setImage("")
      }
    }
  },[text, response])

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topbar}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Pokedex Mobile</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => handleText(value)}
          value={text}
          placeholder="Search Pokemon"
          keyboardType="default"
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
      {image && (
        <Image 
          style={styles.logo} 
          source={{uri : `${image}`}}
          />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text : {
    fontSize: 30,
    color : "red"
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  container : {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center'
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#000'
  },
  topbar: {
  },
  logo : {
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  }
});
```

Comment: Looks like an infinite loop waiting to happen. You type some text which triggers `searchApi(text)` which writes to `response` which triggers your effect hook and because `text` is still _truthy_, it triggers `searchApi(text)` again, _ad infinitum_

Comment: yes, but even doing the search action from a button the image still doesn't appear :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code causes an infinite loop...

1. You type some text which triggers `searchApi(text)`
2. That writes to `response` which triggers your effect hook
3. Because `text` is still *truthy*, it triggers `searchApi(text)` again
4. Goto #2

As far as I can tell, you can simply discard most of `response` and just retrieve the image when the text changes.

```tsx
// this doesn't need to be defined in your component
const getPokemonImage = async (name: string) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${encodeURIComponent(pokemonName)}/`
  );

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`);
  }

  return (await res.json<PokeInterface>()).sprites.front_default;
};

export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState<string>("");
  const [image, setImage] = useState<string>(""); // initial value

  const handleText = (text: string) => {
    setText(text);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (text) {
      getPokemonImage(text)
        .then(setImage)
        .catch(err => {
          console.error("getPokemonImage", err)
          // show an error message or something
        });
    }
  }, [ text ]); // only run on text change
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realized that the error was when searching in the api, the default behavior of the input on the cell phone is to add the first letter in uppercase, and the api is with the pokemon names in lowercase, that is, it was just converting to lowercase before doing the search, but thanks for refactoring the code :)

Comment: @LucasRodriguez that will be caught by the check for `res.ok` in my code. Searching for say _"Pikachu"_ responds with a 404 which will raise an error

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Image, Button} from 'react-native';

// Sorry for removing the types i was using JS
// This code works test it for yourself
export default function App() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('');
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(); // Here use PokeInterface || any as you are doing conditional checking
  const [image, setImage] = useState();
  const handleText = e => {
    setText(e);
  };

  const searchApi = pokemonName => {
    fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonName}/`, {method: 'GET'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setResponse(response));
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    if (response) {
      const {sprites} = response;
      console.log(response);
      setImage(sprites.front_default);
    }
    return () => {
      if (image) {
        setImage('');
      }
    };
  }, [image, text, response]); // you have to pass all the dependencies so useEffect will be invoked as you didnt pass image dep the useeffct was not invoking

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.topbar}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Pokedex Mobile</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          onChangeText={(value: any) => handleText(value)}
          value={text}
          placeholder="Search Pokemon"
          keyboardType="default"
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>{text}</Text>
      </View>
      {image && <Image style={styles.logo} source={{uri: `${image}`}} />}
      <Button
        title={'Submit'}
        onPress={() => searchApi(text)}
        disabled={!text}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: 'red',
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#000',
  },
  topbar: {},
  logo: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I realized that the error was when searching in the api, the default behavior of the input on the cell phone is to add the first letter in uppercase, and the api is with the pokemon names in lowercase, that is, it was just converting to lowercase before doing the search, but thanks for refactoring the code :)